# How to read data sent to an XBee on Windows?

Tags: python, xbee

How can I read the data I am sending to my XBee connected to my Windows machine?

I want to see if the data is being sent correctly, because my code is compiling correctly in IDLE, but if I try to read the serial console in XCTU it says the port is currently being occupied. Any ideas on how to read the data I'm sending?

```
import serial
i = 'A'
ser = serial.Serial('com3',9600,timeout =1)
ser.write(i)
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both XBees connected, while communicating to one in the python code, you have the other in the serial console in XCTU. Writing to the port will display the message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open COM3 in XCTU?  You won't be able to do that since you have it open in Python.  Is that XBee module paired with one on another serial port where you'd be able to see the output?

You might want to add a delay between the `ser.write()` and `ser.close()` calls to ensure you're giving it time to send the data.  It's possible that the first call just queues the data to send.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Python-Xbee library also? It makes decoding packets easier:

https://github.com/nioinnovation/python-xbee

This library also has support for Zigbee.

Jim